# How to get rid of java heap space memory issue in javafx table view?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have written an application where depending on the no of communication between the host and the device it will draw a table view and show the data for each communication (for each new communication a separate table view will be  created). But after doing this I am facing some issue with heap  space memory. After hundreds of tables get created my application is hanging and after that it is crashing, but not before throwing the heap space memory problem. I tried to increase my heap space memory but it did not solve my issue. Any light on this issue will be helpful to me.

Comment: why do you want to create new table for new connection ? ,why not add as new row ..

Comment: Each connection have separate column  name and no of columns.so it will be ambiguous to represent it in one table.

Comment: How many items do you need to store? Are you sure you're not leaking memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem with TableView and collected how to fix this at http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/09/19/memoryleaks-javafx-2-2-tableview-and-friends/

Comment: Tried  your workaround.There is little bit improvement  but it did not solve my problem.Even tried to implement pagination on each page such that each page will contain maximum 10 tables .But it also ended up with java heap space memory error

Comment: All Listiners and callback needed to be disposed individually otherwise it will not release the memory.Anywyz thanks tom for the rescue..

Answer (score 0):

If i were you ,i will not create a new Table for each new Connection ,Because adding more nodes to scene graph will effect performance of application and it will consume more memory.

See this Analysis :

**Application : AllTablesTest**

***1) When launched 2 nodes (Hbox,Button)  Memory Consumed : 40MB***
[image]

**2) I just added 1070 empty tables to scenegraph ,now node count :1071 Memory Consumed : 205MB**

[image]

**3) To make sure i ran sampletest again with 1100 empty tables ,Memory Consumed : 209MB**
[image]

**Application :SingleTableTst**

***1) Node count 3 and row(data count )- 4000 ,Memory Consumed : 47MB***
[image]

Clearly Single table is the winner ,even if table columns a little different for each table try to use single table with more columns .

Comment: @invarient thnaks for your profiling .Now i fixed my no of table to 6 and implemented pagination .It solved my issue.